# can not send email from gmail on window server 2003

Tags: smtp, gmail, windows-server-2003

i have some code below

```
try {
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
    string sBody = null;
    sBody = "body content";

    var _with1 = SmtpServer;
    _with1.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "abc");
    _with1.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    _with1.EnableSsl = true;

    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage()) {
         //mail = New MailMessage()
         var _with2 = mail;
         _with2.From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com");
         _with2.To.Add("cdf@yahoo.com.vn");
         _with2.Subject = "Thông báo có góp ý cho câu hỏi";
         _with2.Body = sBody;
         _with2.IsBodyHtml = true;
         SmtpServer.Send(mail);
     }
 } catch (Exception) {
     throw;
 }
```

it works fine at window 7

But when i run it on window server 2003, it have an error:
"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at"

Please help me fix it!

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the WS2003 computer is initiating a secure connection?

Comment: i dont know, how to know this?

Comment: Use a debugger to step-through your code. Use the remote debugger if you don't have local access to the machine.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477055/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the reason. My account email google need confirm the IP's server and then it work fine :)