# Using MVCMailer in asp.net MVC4 application, keep getting error on email send

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, email, mvcmailer

I am using [MVCMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) as my email harness for all the many email this web app will be sending. Getting emails sent is simple enough, but I can't get it working while I am testing on localhost.

On the site I set it up like it says you need to. My web config has this in it:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <!-- Method#1: Configure smtp server credentials -->
      <smtp from="david.stanley.13@gmail.com">
        <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="david.stanley.13@gmail.com" password="pass" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

I am setting this on top of my Controller:

```
private IUserMailer _userMailer = new UserMailer();
public IUserMailer UserMailer
{
    get { return _userMailer; }
    set { _userMailer = value; }
}
```

And this is where I am calling the 'Send' Method to test the welcome message (inside an ActionResult Method):

```
_userMailer.Welcome(model.EmailAddress, model.FirstName + " " + model.LastName).Send();
```

I believe that I did not miss anything in the tutorial linked about, but when stepping through the code I get this error:

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.
```

A few questions I guess:

1. Is there a setting I can do to make this run?
2. If I have 2-Factor auth on my gmail, is that going to interfere?
3. Am I missing something so obvious I will want to delete this question?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

1. The password was a joke, I am not that dumb, give me *some* credit.. :)

The Send() implementation does this (its built into MVC mailer):

```
public virtual MvcMailMessage Welcome(string email, string fullName)
{
//ViewBag.Data = someObject;
return Populate(x =>
{
    x.Subject = "Welcome to eTrail Cub Tracking " + fullName;
    x.ViewName = "Welcome";
    x.To.Add(email);
});
}
```

Comment: Did you check the way in which your configuration was being read by the MVCMailer. I guess that you should take a look at that part first.

Comment: what do you mean check the way it is being read?

Comment: Is that your actual gmail password?....

Comment: Seriously, dude ... I hope it's not gonna show in the edits ... You might wanna change it

Comment: No, but I wanted to see if people would try it

Comment: It's still visible in the edits. If it is your password.. definitely change it now.

Comment: A joke only. Though iluvcats4eva is probably a common password. Anywho... Any ideas on the issue? I should no I am using IIS Express.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477055/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov - thanks, using that question I was able to mush some code together to get it to send, BUT, on my wifes email account (no 2-factor auth) in worked fine. The same code did NOT work on my account. Maybe there is not a work around for that, but at least I rooted out the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is your issue, but it looks like you forgot to setup the default delivery method on your config.

You have

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <!-- Method#1: Configure smtp server credentials -->
      <smtp from="david.stanley.13@gmail.com">
        <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="david.stanley.13@gmail.com" password="pass" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Try :

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <!-- Method#1: Configure smtp server credentials -->
      <smtp from="david.stanley.13@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="david.stanley.13@gmail.com" password="pass" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

I would also try to just use the **SmtpClient** directly in a code sample without MvcMailer and see if the issue is just a configuration one.

Comment: I had the same problem. Adding `deliveryMethod="Network"` solved it. Thanks.

Comment: I thought adding the deliveryMethod attribute won't help me. However, it was the one that fixed my email issue not being sent. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you are missing something untowards: `smtp.Send(x);`

try:

```
public virtual MvcMailMessage Welcome(string email, string fullName)
{

    //ViewBag.Data = someObject;

    return Populate(x =>
    {
        x.Subject = "Welcome to eTrail Cub Tracking " + fullName;
        x.ViewName = "Welcome";
        x.To.Add(email);
        stmp.send(x);
    });
}
```